# Python Memory Error (Unix vs Windows)

Tags: python, linux, memory

I am developing an application which loads big JPEG2000 images and converts them to TIF. Later on, it extracts the pixel data and there is some processing. It perfectly works except in one case:

When I load the biggest image and extract the data (10956x10956 array) the program crashes but it only crashes on Windows -- never on Linux. (I'd like a portable application).

I detected the problem and it is because of a memory error when interpolating 20x20 to the image sampling.

```
f=RectBivariateSpline(x,y,Sun_angles)

xnew = numpy.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),rows)

ynew = numpy.linspace(y.min(),y.max(),columns)

Sun_angles_new = f(xnew, ynew) #here it crashes
```

I also tried with `interp2d` and `mapcoordinates` and I got the same result.

Python is supposed to be completely portable but I've got the impression is optimised for Unix systems (see also: [Running python on a Windows machine vs Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765178/running-python-on-a-windows-machine-vs-linux))

Note: I run the program on two different computers but with the same processor and RAM.

Therefore... what could be the reason? And is there any other interpolation with less memory consumption?

Note: One solution is dividing the image in tiles and interpolate.

Comment: Which architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) is each OS?

Comment: I checked again and the memory is the same but the processors are different. In windows it is a Core2Duo 32 bits and in linux an Intel i5 64 bits...sorry.

Comment: Possibly there is a different instruction set or other causes but the dynamic memory it's still the same....

Comment: All Core 2 CPUs are 64-bit, but that doesn't mean much. In Windows, you can check the actual running architecture by looking at the "System Type" entry in the Computer properties window (right-click on "Computer" in the start menu). On Linux, you can run `getconf LONG_BIT`, which will print either `32` or `64`.

Answer (score 4):

You should examine the memory use of the application under windows. Considering that the size of the raw image is going to be ~360MB (assuming a 24bit image) if you are allocating memory for each pixel, this is going to multiply, and could easily exceed the memory requirements of a 32bit address space (You are limited to ~2GB for windows applications)

On linux, you are probably running a 64bit linux, which is running a 64bit version of python. The limit there is pretty much unreachable for a desktop application (you will run out of swap space well before you run out of address space).

Comment: Yes, the image is big but no so much (~250M since it is codified with 12 bits). You are right, when I reach 2.32M, the program shows Memory error. I tried to split the image, interpolate by pieces...but it is useless. In the end I need to join all the pieces in one and then it crashes again....